# Error building GHC on Windows

Tags: haskell, ghc

While attempting to bootstrap Haskell on Windows without the Haskell Platform I ran into the following error

> C:\git\Haskell\ghc\libraries\haskeline\dist-install\build/libHShaskeline-0.7.1.2.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

Note that `C:\git\Haskell\ghc` is where I put the `ghc` git repo.

However whenever I looked at the file it appeared to be building correctly.

I have attempted completely clean rebuilds, and deleting the whole repo and regetting it, everything short of deleting anything related to this build and starting fresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually figured out what was causing the issue, I realized it when I found the following notice on the [Windows Platform notes for GHC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Platforms/Windows#GHCTargetsMinGW).

> However, the makefiles do use whatever ld and ar happen to be in your path.

This didn't seem right, and reading the configure script I noticed the following lines:

```
mingwbin="$hardtop/inplace/mingw/bin/"
LD="${mingwbin}ld.exe"
```

Note that `mingwbin` refers to the location that the tarballs are extracted to. Looking at the timestamps of the executables did not match up to the version that `which ld` returned (in `/mingw/bin`).

Given the note that meant that at some point `/inplace/mingw/bin/ld.exe` was being used while at another point `/mingw/bin/ld.exe` was being used, possibly causing the issue.

Running the following command before `make` resolved the issue.

```
export PATH=/c/git/Haskell/git/inplace/mingw/bin:$PATH
```